# saddle point of $f(x,y)=x^6-2x^2y-x^4y+2y^2$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

> $$f(x,y)=x^6-2x^2y-x^4y+2y^2$$

Then which of following is true

> $1).$ $f$ has a saddle point at origin
>
> $2)$. The origin is not a critical point $f$

**Solution I tried**-Here i find the $f_{xx}(0,0),f_{yy}(0,0)$ and $f_{xy}(0,0)$ all i get is $0$ $i.e$ the value of $D$

> $$D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$$
> i get this value zero and according to rule we cant say anything about this ,
> i have no idea how to proccede further

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

$(0,0)$ is a critical point because $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$. As you said, the second partial derivative test fails. To see that it's a saddle point, note we have the factorization $f(x,y)=(x^4-2y)(x^2-y)$. Then $f(x,x^3)=x^4(x-2)(1-x)x$, so $f(x,x^3)>0$ for $-1<x<0$ and $f(x,x^3)<0$ for $0<x<1$. That is, you have both negative and positive values around $(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

As an alternative, $x=0$ is a local minimum point for $f(x,x)=x^2(x^3-2)(x-1)$ and a local maximum point for $f\left(x,\frac{x^2}{2}\right)=\frac{x^4}{2}(x^2-1)$.